# Split sprintf() in foreach loop

Tags: php

A simple question i can't figure out. I'm having this simple sendmail script in php.
But i need the printet array (that prints the body of the email) to be splittet up.

What is the simplest solution to make the outcome from the foreach loop be:
1. In the first 4 posts in the array, only the value and not the key from the post is printet
2. The rest of the array is printet, both keys and values.
I'm currently using this:

```
 foreach($fields as $a => $b){ $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }
```

Can't seem to get my head around it. Any help is very welcome!
Troels

Comment: Add a counter, add an if-statement for >=4. Refine later ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like?

```
$i = 0;
foreach($fields as $a => $b) {
 $i++;
 if ($i>3) $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);
}
```

Comment: $i = 0;  
foreach($fields as $a => $b) {  
 $i++;  
 if ($i>3) $body .= sprintf("%s\n",$_REQUEST[$a]);  
else $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);  
}  
  
Guess this is then a decent solution